# Grep file extension using regular expression

Tags: regex, xslt

I have filenames for examples as below names

1) "Wireshark-win64-1.12.5.exe"
2) "Service - Document.docx"

Is there anyway I can grep the file extension using some generic regular expression and save it in a xslt variable. I was using some string function as below, but for value such as shown above in 1), it won't work.

```
<xsl:variable name="fileExtension" select="substring-before(substring-after($filename,'.'),'&quot;')"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using XSLT 2.0, then:

```
tokenize($filename, '\.')[last()]
```

will extract the file extension from *$filename* for you.

Comment: Looks like datapower firmware version I am using, does not support XSLT 2.0. I am not able to get the file extension.

Comment: There is no regex support in XSLT 1.0. However, I believe IBM DataPower supports a number of extension, among them the EXSLT str:tokenize() extension function: http://exslt.org/str/functions/tokenize/index.html